# Why do we have to call `.done()` at the end of a promise chain in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the [react-native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content) it says:

> Note that we call done() at the end of the promise chain - always make
>   sure to call done() or any errors thrown will get swallowed.

```
 fetchData: function() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          movies: responseData.movies,
        });
      })
      .done();
  },
```

What does this empty .`done()` actually do?

Comment: "[Unhandled exceptions in a `then` function are silently captured as part of the state of the promise, but unhandled exceptions in a `done` function are thrown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700337.aspx)." If you don't do a `done`, then any error that occurs is stored inside the promise, and then you throw the promise away and you never learn about the error.

Comment: I imagine this is the beginning of understanding what is happening, but what does it mean that the done is not taking an argument?   What does the `done` actually _do_?

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701079.aspx) explains what happens when you don't pass a value. (Basically, nothing happens.) The point is that `done` raises the exception if nobody handles it, whereas `then` saves the exception in the promise so it can propagate it into the next `then` call. The problem is that if there is no next `then`, then the exception never gets propagated to anywhere; it just vanishes. The upshot is that an empty `done` means "Raise any pending exception now."

Comment: @RaymondChen you should transform  your comments into answer

Comment: @EugeneSafronov I had originally hoped that a nudge would be sufficient. Didn't intend it to turn into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I needed clarified:

- Exceptions encountered in promises (during execution of the `then()` callback) are stored as an `Error` object, and **not thrown**.

This mechanism means that you can defer actions without risk of exceptions inside them messing you up at a random time.

- `done()` called without argument on a promise looks into the promise to see if there are any stored exceptions, and throws them.

This means that you can take care of exceptions during promise processing, at the end of the promise processing.