# ReactJS not rendering my API call results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

In React, I have a state called views_res which is a list. I make an API call in viewsList(), which is supposed to map the results of the API call to this state variable. However, when I debug using console.log(), I see the "start" and "WHAT UP DOE," but the views is empty :(

I know that the API end point is correct, as Postman shows me the correct JSON response. However, my state variable is simply not receiving the data. I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this!

For privacy, I redacted the exact API end point.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.ViewsList();
  }

  // Gets views from Wistia API
   ViewsList() {
    console.log("start", this.state.views);
// API call
$.getJSON(
  "url"
)
  // JSON format
  .then(response => {
    response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Map over data
    let views_res = data.response.map(item => (
      <div>
        console.log("play_count", {item.play_count})
        <h1>{item.play_count}</h1> */}
      </div>
    ));
    // Set the state
    this.setState({ views: views_res });
  });
console.log("WHAT UP DOE", this.state.views);
  }
```

Comment: are you binding `ViewsList` to the class? in the constructor `this.ViewsList = this.ViewsList.bind(this)`

Comment: setState is async as well. you can veiw it in the callback second option on setState

Comment: Hi, I am binding ViewList to the class. But I don't know what you mean when you say I can view the "callback second option". Sorry

Comment: `this.setState({ views: views_res }, () => { console.log(this.state.views)});`

Comment: Also, don't create your JSX code like this. Get the data, set it as your state then create your JSX in your `render` method as usual.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the response to json and pass it along to the next section? Because with the brackets, the `response.json();` won't get returned for use in the next `then()`. Does `"play_count"` get printed? Also note this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194423/why-do-we-have-to-call-done-at-the-end-of-a-promise-chain-in-react-native. (It's promises in general, not just react-native)

Comment: @HammerN'Songs No, "play_count" does not get printed even if I remove the brackets from around response.json()

Comment: @JohnRuddell I tried that, but it did not resolve it.

Comment: @devserkan Is that better styling?

Comment: `.then(response => response.json())`?

Comment: @JuniusL. I tried that, per HammerN'Songs response, but it did not fix things

Comment: try adding catch block `.then(data => ...).catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: I'd advise trying adding a `.done()` to the end of the `promise.then().then()` chain (see link in previous comment), and check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of library you're using for `$.getJson` (is it `jQuery`?) but note that `setState` [is an asynchronous operation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Meaning, you want "see" the changes if you `console.log` after you called `setState`.
There is a second argument though for `setState` which is a callback function that will get triggered after the actual update of the state.

```
this.setState({ views: views_res }, () => {
    // this is a callback function for setState.
  // this coode will run just after the state actually updated
  console.log("WHAT UP DOE", this.state.views)
})
```

From the DOCS:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied

**Edit**
Note that this part:

```
<div>
  console.log("play_count", {item.play_count})
  <h1>{item.play_count}</h1> */}
</div>
```

Will not log anything, as

```
console.log("play_count", {item.play_count})
```

Is just a string inside a `JSX` block. If you want to write JavaScript expressions inside a `JSX` block, you should wrap it with curly braces (`{}`):

See a running example:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
     <div>
        console.log("i am just a string")
        {console.log('I will show in the console')}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
```

Comment: but `play_count` doesn't get logged which means that state doesn't even get sets.

Comment: why should it log it? its just a `string` inside a `JSX` block