# Should I use .done after the last promise?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

In react-native, unhandled promises are silent. There used to be an "Unhandled Promises Rejection" warning, but now I don't see it anymore. Someone knows what happen to that?

I've discovered that putting .done() after a promise, will raise an error if the promise was rejected.

Suppose that I have a promise that is suppose to never be rejected, should I put .done after it, just to detect possible errors?

```js
const asyncFunc = async () => {
   const a = null;

  return a.undefinedField;
}

<Button onPress={() => asyncFunc()} />
<Button onPress={() => asyncFunc().done()} />
```

I'm using react-native which uses [promise (Github)](https://github.com/then/promise).

By done I'm referring the one explained here: [Promise API Reference](https://www.promisejs.org/api/).

There was already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194423/why-do-we-have-to-call-done-at-the-end-of-a-promise-chain-in-react-native), but it's 5 years old and the react-native project changes very fast.

Comment: Where did you get "done" from? Did you mean "finally"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194423/why-do-we-have-to-call-done-at-the-end-of-a-promise-chain-in-react-native

Comment: Looks like promises in jQuery have a done() method. Is this what you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Promise does not have `done` function.

You can catch possible errors in `catch` and place things to do in regardless of success in `finally`.

For example:

```js
const asyncFunc = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      throw new Error('Error');
      resolve('Result');
   })
}
asyncFunc().then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);
}).finally(() => {
  console.log('This will be executed in regardless of success');
});
```

If you're using async - await, you can use try-catch as you can for other functions:

```js
const asyncFunc = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      throw new Error('Error');
      resolve('Result');
   })
}

const executeAsyncFunc = async () => {
  try {
    await asyncFunc();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);  
  } finally {
    console.log('This will be executed in regardless of success');
  }
};

executeAsyncFunc();
```

Comment: They do have, I'm talking react-native here.